# How to Hide a Collapsible table (except for top row) by default

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following html and would like to hide the collapsible table by default, only showing the top row. Which when clicked on, will pop out the rest of the table. Right now, it shows the whole table, only to hide once toggled.

```
<html>

<style>

table { 
    width: 300px; 
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-color: grey;
    line-height: 1.7;
    }

th { 
    background: #ffffff; 
    color: #000000; 
    font-weight: bold;
    }

td, th { 

    border: 1px solid #ccc; 
    text-align: center; 
    font-size: 14px;
    }

td {
 color: #000000;
 }

.labels tr td {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #feb330;
}

.label tr td label {
    display: block;
}

.bold {
font-weight: bold;
}


[data-toggle="toggle"] {
    display: none;
}

</style>

<table>

       <tbody class="labels">

        <tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
            <td colspan="3">
            <label for="14Season">2014 Season: 19</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="14Season" id="14Season" data-toggle="toggle">
        </tr>

        </tbody>

        <tbody class="hide">

            <tr bgcolor="#264033">
                <td class="bold" colspan="1" style="color:#ffffff">Date</td>
                <td class="bold" colspan="1" style="color:#ffffff">Scorigami</td>
                <td class="bold" colspan="1" style="color:#ffffff">Total</td>
            </tr>

            <tr bgcolor="#000000">
                <td style="color:#ffffff">9/21/13</td>
                <td style="color:#ffffff">0-6 L</td>
                <td style="color:#ffffff">1</td>
            </tr>

            <tr bgcolor="#264033">
                <td style="color:#ffffff">9/21/13</td>
                <td style="color:#ffffff">8-10 L</td>
                <td style="color:#ffffff">2</td>
            </tr>

            <tr bgcolor="#000000">
                <td style="color:#ffffff">9/22/13</td>
                <td style="color:#ffffff">10-8 W</td>
                <td style="color:#ffffff">3</td>
            </tr>

            <tr bgcolor="#264033">
                <td style="color:#ffffff">10/19/13</td>
                <td style="color:#ffffff">3-2 W</td>
                <td style="color:#ffffff">4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr bgcolor="#000000">
                <td style="color:#ffffff">10/19/13</td>
                <td style="color:#ffffff">1-4 L</td>
                <td style="color:#ffffff">5</td>
            </tr>

            <tr bgcolor="#264033">
                <td style="color:#ffffff">10/26/13</td>
                <td style="color:#ffffff">7-0 W</td>
                <td style="color:#ffffff">6</td>
            </tr>

            <tr bgcolor="#000000">
                <td style="color:#ffffff">4/11/14</td>
                <td style="color:#ffffff">7-2 W</td>
                <td style="color:#ffffff">7</td>
            </tr>

            <tr bgcolor="#264033">
                <td style="color:#ffffff">4/11/14</td>
                <td style="color:#ffffff">7-1 W</td>
                <td style="color:#ffffff">8</td>
            </tr>

            <tr bgcolor="#000000">
                <td style="color:#ffffff">4/12/14</td>
                <td style="color:#ffffff">13-6 W</td>
                <td style="color:#ffffff">9</td>
            </tr>

            <tr bgcolor="#264033">
                <td style="color:#ffffff">4/12/14</td>
                <td style="color:#ffffff">10-2 W</td>
                <td style="color:#ffffff">10</td>
            </tr>

            <tr bgcolor="#000000">
                <td style="color:#ffffff">4/13/14</td>
                <td style="color:#ffffff">12-0 W</td>
                <td style="color:#ffffff">11</td>
            </tr>

            <tr bgcolor="#264033">
                <td style="color:#ffffff">4/26/14</td>
                <td style="color:#ffffff">8-2 W</td>
                <td style="color:#ffffff">12</td>
            </tr>

            <tr bgcolor="#000000">
                <td style="color:#ffffff">4/26/14</td>
                <td style="color:#ffffff">7-5 W</td>
                <td style="color:#ffffff">13</td>
            </tr>

            <tr bgcolor="#264033">
                <td style="color:#ffffff">4/27/14</td>
                <td style="color:#ffffff">9-1 W</td>
                <td style="color:#ffffff">14</td>
            </tr>

            <tr bgcolor="#000000">
                <td style="color:#ffffff">5/2/14</td>
                <td style="color:#ffffff">10-0 W</td>
                <td style="color:#ffffff">15</td>
            </tr>

            <tr bgcolor="#264033">
                <td style="color:#ffffff">5/3/14</td>
                <td style="color:#ffffff">4-2 W</td>
                <td style="color:#ffffff">16</td>
            </tr>

            <tr bgcolor="#000000">
                <td style="color:#ffffff">5/4/14</td>
                <td style="color:#ffffff">10-4 W</td>
                <td style="color:#ffffff">17</td>
            </tr>

            <tr bgcolor="#264033">
                <td style="color:#ffffff">5/16/14</td>
                <td style="color:#ffffff">1-2 L</td>
                <td style="color:#ffffff">18</td>
            </tr>

            <tr bgcolor="#000000">
                <td style="color:#ffffff">5/17/14</td>
                <td style="color:#ffffff">7-12 L</td>
                <td style="color:#ffffff">19</td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>

</table>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[data-toggle="toggle"]').change(function(){
        $(this).parents().next('.hide').toggle();
    });
});

</script>


</html>
```

I believe only a small change is required, but can't seem to get it right. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Adding

```
.hide {
display: none;
}
```

fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
table { 
    display: none;
}
```

this should work. Also change,

```
[data-toggle="toggle"] {
     display: block;
}
```

Comment: This will hide the entire table by default. I am looking for the top row to always be visible, with the rest being hidden by default until the top row is toggled.

Comment: unfortunately the above addition rendered the same outcome

Answer (score 0):

you can give to the table rows logical id's, then use a function to hide/show them

code to retrieve the table rows id's

```
  var table = document.querySelector('table');

  // listen for a click
   table.addEventListener('click', function(ev){
    // get the event targets ID
    var serviceID = ev.target.id;
    alert(serviceID);
})
```